# jQuery each function not working for appending querystring to URL

Tags: html, jquery

I am attempting to write a jQuery function that appends a querystring to a URL with values from a few select dropdowns. I will have multiple instances of these forms on the page, and they will have the same classes. I want to isolate the values to the specific form using one function by using the jQuery each method. However, when filling out one of the custom search forms, it grabs the value from a different form on the page. Can anyone help me re-write this so the values appended to the URL are isolated to the specific form you are interacting with?

```
$('.custom-search').each(function () {
var minprice = $(this).find('.price-min');
var maxprice = $(this).find('.price-max');
var product = $(this).find('.product');
$('.custom-search-btn').bind('click', function () {
    var url = '/products/?product-view=1&minPrice=' + encodeURIComponent(minprice.val()) + '&maxPrice=' + encodeURIComponent(maxprice.val()) + '&productName=' + encodeURIComponent(product.val());
    window.location.href = url;
});});


    <div class="custom-search">
     <div class="form-group price-min-group">
        <label for="Price-min">Min Price</label>
        <select name="Price[min]" class="form-control price-min">
           <option value="">Min Price </option>
           <option value="0">$0</option>
           <option value="500">$500</option>
           <option value="750">$750</option>
           <option value="1000">$1,000</option>
           <option value="1250">$1,250</option>
           <option value="1500">$1,500</option>
           <option value="1750">$1,750</option>
        </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group price-max-group">
        <label for="Price-max">Max Price</label>
        <select name="Price[max]" class="form-control price-max">
           <option value="">Max Price </option>
           <option value="">No maximum</option>
           <option value="500">$500</option>
           <option value="750">$750</option>
           <option value="1000">$1,000</option>
           <option value="1250">$1,250</option>
           <option value="1500">$1,500</option>
           <option value="1750">$1,750</option>
           <option value="2000">$2,000</option>
        </select>
     </div>
    <div class="form-group hidden">
     <select name="City State" class="form-control product hidden">
       <option value="Eggs">Eggs</option>
     </select>
   </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default usm-btn submit custom-search-btn" value="Search">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're adding a `click` handler in every round of the `.each()` loop on every `.custom-search-btn` element in the DOM. Two forms = two `click` handlers on every button.

Comment: A `console.log(url)` instead of the redirect would have made this quite obvious.

Comment: @Andreas yep that was it thank you!